# How to add textbox values to datagrid in UWP? and it has a calculated field called approx cost

Tags: uwp

____________These are input fields of textboxes____________

```
    <Canvas Margin="20,36,0,4" CanBeScrollAnchor="True">

        <TextBox x:Name="srno" Width="72" Text="{Binding SrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"  PlaceholderText="Sr No." Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="Default" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" InputScope="Number"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Itemne" Width="252" Text="{Binding Item_Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" PlaceholderText="Item Name" Canvas.Left="153" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="Default" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Make_Brand" Width="140" Text="{Binding Make_Brand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" PlaceholderText="Make/Brand" Canvas.Left="430" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="Default" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="UOM" Width="108" Text="{Binding UoM, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="UoM" Canvas.Left="592" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="Default" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox x:Name="quantity" Width="100" Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Quantity"  Canvas.Left="735" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="Default" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox x:Name="UnitCost" Width="138" Text="{Binding Unit_Cost, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Unit Cost" Canvas.Left="857" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="Default" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Content="Add" Canvas.Left="1048" Canvas.Top="412" Height="34" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12" Click="Button_Add_Click" Width="107"/>
```

________________-this is a datagrid______________________

```
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Canvas.Left="52" Canvas.Top="487" Height="157" Width="1151" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Sr No" Binding="{Binding SrNo1}" Width="100"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding Item_Name1}" Width="300"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Make/Brand" Binding="{Binding Make_Brand1}" Width="150"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="UoM" Binding="{Binding UoM1}" Width="150" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity1}" Width="150" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Cost" Binding="{Binding Unit_Cost1}" Width="150" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Approx cost" Binding="{Binding Approxcost1}" Width="150" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Indent No" Binding="{Binding IndentNo1}" Width="150" />

            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>

    </Canvas>
```

Please tell how to tackle this

Comment: Hi, does the following method help? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a view model which contains the properties you want to bind with DataGridTextColumn. Then create a List to bind with the ItemsSource of DataGrid, when you click the Button to try to add the values to DataGrid, you can add value into the list, then the UI will also update. For example:

.cs:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string srNo1;
    public string SrNo1 {
        get {
            return srNo1;
        }
        set {
            srNo1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string item_Name1;
    public string Item_Name1
    {
        get
        {
            return item_Name1;
        }
        set
        {
            item_Name1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string make_Brand1;
    public string Make_Brand1
    {
        get
        {
            return make_Brand1;
        }
        set
        {
            make_Brand1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ......
    // other proeprties

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}


public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Lists = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> Lists { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        vm.SrNo1 = srno.Text;
        vm.Item_Name1 = Itemne.Text;
        vm.Make_Brand1 = Make_Brand.Text;
        vm.UoM1 = UOM.Text;
        vm.Quantity1 = quantity.Text;
        vm.Unit_Cost1 = UnitCost.Text;
        vm.Approxcost1 = //Your calculation
        Lists.Add(vm);
    }
}
```

.xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Lists,Mode=OneWay}".....>
......
</controls:DataGrid>
```